# show recent posts php code error?

Tags: php, posts, homepage

I'm using this code to show my recent posts in my website:

```
<div class="post_content">
        <div class="home_posts">
            <?php
                $args2 = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => 6,
                'order_by'=>'post_date',
                'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
                );
                $query = new WP_Query( $args2 );
                if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
                    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                        echo '<div class="grid_post">
                                <h3><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h3>';
                        $type = get_post_meta($post->ID,'page_featured_type',true);
                        switch ($type) {
                            case 'youtube':
                                echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'page_video_id', true ).'?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                                break;
                            case 'vimeo':
                                echo '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'page_video_id', true ).'?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=03b3fc" width="500" height="338" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';
                                break;
                            default:
                                echo '<div class="grid_post_img">
                                            <a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail().'</a>
                                        </div>';
                                break;
                        }
                        echo '<div class="grid_home_posts">
                                    <p>'.dess_get_excerpt(120).'</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            ';
                    endwhile;
            ?>
    </div>
```

However, it shows the posts from my "beauty" section. Also, I found that in that page, there is this code:

```
[posts-for-page cat_slug='beauty' hide_images='false' num='10' read_more='
Read More »' show_full_posts='false' use_wp_excerpt='true' strip_html='true'     
hide_post_content='false' show_meta='false' force_image_height='200'  
force_image_width='250']
```

Do you know how to change it, please? This is my website: [www.wha2wear.com](http://www.wha2wear.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have the [Posts for Page plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-for-page/) installed. I don't know where you have put that code you mention, but the page is generated by the shortcode, which says that output should be limited to the beauty category. You probably don't need to write code yourself. Read the manual of the plugin and change the shortcode accordingly.

Comment: thank you! you are right, I just changed *posts-for-page cat_slug='beauty'* by *posts-for-page order_by='date'* and it works :)